# Possible to pass arguments to CSS classes?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="center small-top-margin">
  <%= rails code %>
</div>
```

where `small-top-margin' is as follows:

```
.small-top-margin {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Is there a way to pass an argument to a css class such that

`class="top-margin(2)` #=> `margin-top: 2em;`
`class="top-margin(5)` #=> `margin-top: 5em;`
etc..

or even better

`class="margin(top, 2)` #=> `margin-top: 2em;`

I've included `Rails` tags in case there's a way to do this through rails, although a purely css/sass solution would be better.

Comment: Not possible to send as parameter to css class

Comment: No. I highly doubt it. SASS works by compiling CSS, but `class="identifier"` is not CSS. It is HTML, and it is likley contained in an `ERB` file. You pass arguments to CSS via naming structures, like `top-margin-2`, and you can create dynamically named classes from within SASS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496353/create-dynamic-class-names-using-while-loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. But you can generate a reasonable number of pre-built classes:

```
.top-margin-2 {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
.top-margin-5 {
    margin-top: 5em;
}
```

Then you can generate your HTML with `class="top-margin-#{margin}"`

This is not usually a good thing, but if you really need it, it's possible. I urge you though to reconsider and ask what you *really* want; CSS classes should be semantically meaningful, otherwise you might as well directly apply the CSS on the elements' style attribute. What does `2em` mean to you? What is `5em`?

Comment: you're right about 'might as well directly apply' to the style attr.  Was more interested if there was a way I could minimize CSS classes, but again you're right - reasonable number seems like the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.

Use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass parameters to CSS file by using php.
1. Create your style by name style.php as:

```
<?php
/*** set the content type header ***/
header("Content-type: text/css");
/** set the  color ***/
$page = $_GET['page'];
$font_size = $_GET['font_size'];
if($page==1){
  $color = 'red';
}else{
  $color = 'yellow';
}
?>
#test{
  color:<?=$color;?>;
  font-size:<?=$font_size;?>;
}
```

1. In html file call style.php and pass parameter to it

   \link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" 
   href="/css/style.php?page=1&font_size=35px"/>

   div id="test">Test test /div>