# Pass dynamic Values to the SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I am using SCSS for the style sheet and I am just getting used to it.

Would like to get a little suggestion on the following scenario.

Say I got three div tags with following in-line params,

```
<div style="margin-top:10px">....</div>
<div style="margin-top:-10px">....</div>
<div style="margin-top:30px">....</div>
```

Now I could create 3 CSS class style with different values to avoid in-line css.

However is there a way I could create a single class as margin-top and pass the values 10px , -10px and 30px for each div.

Comment: You can make use of SCSS functions and send parameters as 10px ,-10 and 30 but i doubt we cannot do as the way ur expecting in css

Comment: Is there some examples I can follow to achieve the same with SCSS? could not find it how to pass the value from html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mixins http://thesassway.com/advanced/pure-sass-functions

```
@mixin my-mixin($some-number) {
     margin-top: $some-number;
 }
```

Now we use the @include directive to insert our mixin's code.

```
div.some-class {
  @include my-mixin(10px);
}
```

Now if you decide you also want to set margin-bottom, you can do it from a single place

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of scss functions here. You can write a function for margin-top and which accepts a parameter

```
 @mixin margintop($top){
        margin-top:$top;
    }
```

and for each separate div you can send as different parameters as

```
div:first-child{
  @include margintop(10px);
}
div:nth-child(2){
  @include margintop(-10px);
}
div:nth-child(3){
  @include margintop(30px);
}
```

Apart from this ,we cannot access scss functions in html and send parameters to it

this reference could be helpful to you [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831328/possible-to-pass-arguments-to-css-classes)

Hope it helps

Comment: aah yea mixin could be of better use

Comment: Mmm...  you modified it so it looks like my answer? May as well delete it?